# Modify $pattern to get the desired result with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following code, which I need to tweak, in order to get the desired **echo**.

```
<?php

$price = "A1,500.99B";

$pattern = '/([\d,]+\.)(\d+)(.*)$/';   // This is something that I need to change, in order to get the desired result

$formatted_1 = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $price);
$formatted_2 = preg_replace($pattern, '$2', $price);
$formatted_3 = preg_replace($pattern, '$3', $price);
$formatted_4 = preg_replace($pattern, '$4', $price);

echo $formatted_1;   // Should give A
echo $formatted_2;   // Should give 1,500
echo $formatted_3;   // Should give 99
echo $formatted_4;   // Should give B

?>
```

I know that I should add another **( )** with something inside, within the **$pattern**, as well as tweak the above **$pattern**, but I have no idea what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: removed design-pattern tag since this doesn't relate to design patterns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any particular reason to use preg_replace if you just want a match?

This pattern will match your price:

```
/([a-zA-Z])([\d,]+)\.(\d+)([a-zA-Z])/
```

If you then write this PHP:

```
$price = "A1,500.99B";
//Match any letter followed by at least one decimal digit or comma 
//followed by a dot followed by a number of digits followed by a letter
$pattern = '/([a-zA-Z])([\d,]+)\.(\d+)([a-zA-Z])/';
preg_match($pattern,$price,$match);

$formatted_1 = $match[1];
//etc...
```

You will have the four matches.  Obviously you need to add your own exception handling.

Comment: If I replace only the $pattern in my code, it works, but any ides how the $pattern would look like, if I have $price = "$1,500.99$"; or $price = "€1,500.99€"; or $price = "£1,500.99£"; or any combination of those signs?

Comment: I use [a-zA-Z] only because your example had A and B.  You could change that to [^\d] if you are happy to match any none digit character at the beginning and end, i.e. $, £, A, _, " it would match any of those as an example. /([^\d])([\d,]+)\.(\d+)([^\d])/

Comment: Yeap, I think this one is the winner :) Can you please tell me how can I loose the comma in 1,500 if I need to? Thanks. Let me test this a little bit, and I'll check your answer and the comment ;)

Comment: Hm, how do you mean optional? Optional in $price = "A1,500.99B"; or optional in /([^\d])([\d,]+)\.(\d+)([^\d])/ ?

Comment: After the first character, and before the dot, the pattern is only looking for at least one digit or comma.  If you enter a $price of A1500.99B it will still match as A 1500 99 B even without a comma in there.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$pattern = '/([0-9a-zA-Z,]+\.)(\d+)(.*)$/';
```

Comment: Nope, you still have 3 parts, I think you'll need to add another ( ) at the beginning...